# Swift 3: Add text to label if button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

In my Xcode project, I have five empty text labels (i.e. I, II, III, IV, V) and five buttons, each representing one letter (i.e. a, b, c, d, e).

I'd like to fill the text labels I to V with the letters, **but in the order the letter buttons are pressed** (i.e. *user presses c* → label **I** contains letter **c**; then *user presses a* → label **II** contains letter **a** and so on).

Could you give me any hint / solution how to do this?

Thanks,
J.

*Edit:* After Benjamins suggestion, I have now done the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    // Letter Buttons
@IBOutlet weak var LetterOneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterTwoButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterThreeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterFourButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LetterFiveButton: UIButton!

// Word Fields
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterThree: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFour: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFive: UILabel!

// Counter
@IBOutlet weak var CounterLabel: UILabel!

// Skip Button
@IBOutlet weak var SkipButtonLabel: UIButton!

// Define Variables
var index: Int = 0
var labels: [UILabel] = [WordLetterOne, WordLetterTwo, WordLetterThree, WordLetterFour, WordLetterFive]
var letters: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set initial letters for LetterButtons
    LetterOneButton.setTitle("A", for: .normal)
    LetterTwoButton.setTitle("U", for: .normal)
    LetterThreeButton.setTitle("T", for: .normal)
    LetterFourButton.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
    LetterFiveButton.setTitle("S", for: .normal)

    // Add button content to WordField
    // Second Attempt

    //you need to set the tags of each button in order for my method to work
    LetterOneButton.tag = 0
    LetterTwoButton.tag = 1
    LetterThreeButton.tag = 2
    LetterFourButton.tag = 3
    LetterFiveButton.tag = 4

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



}

// Add button content to WordField
// First Attempt

@IBAction func LetterOneButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    labels[index].text = letters[sender.tag]

    index += 1
}

/**
@IBAction func LetterTwoButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    WordLetterTwo.text = LetterTwoButton.currentTitle
}

@IBAction func LetterThreeButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    WordLetterThree.text = LetterThreeButton.currentTitle
}

@IBAction func LetterFourButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    WordLetterFour.text = LetterFourButton.currentTitle
}

@IBAction func LetterFiveButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    WordLetterFive.text = LetterFiveButton.currentTitle
} **/




// Skip Button Action
@IBAction func SkipButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
}

}
```

Comment: How do you tell that the entire press-button session has ended?  What if the user taps the same button twice?

Comment: Each button is disabled after it was touched, until all five of them were touched.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Create an array and put the letter corresponding to the button whenever the user taps any of them.  Then sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is placing your labels and letters in an array:

```
var labels: [UILabel] = [label1, label2, ...]
var letters: [String] = ["a", "b", ...]
```

Then you could create a class variable to keep track of how many buttons have been pressed:

```
var index: Int = 0
```

Then in a IBAction that all the buttons are linked to for "touchUpInside" you could take all of this information and populate one label each time it is called. This of course would require you to set your buttons' tags as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (for a through e respectively).

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){

    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        labels[index].text = letters[sender.tag]
    ...
    }

    index += 1

}
```

EDIT:

After seeing your code, you should change it to something like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set initial letters for LetterButtons
    LetterOneButton.setTitle("A", for: .normal)
    LetterTwoButton.setTitle("U", for: .normal)
    LetterThreeButton.setTitle("T", for: .normal)
    LetterFourButton.setTitle("O", for: .normal)
    LetterFiveButton.setTitle("S", for: .normal)

    // Add button content to WordField
    // Second Attempt

    //initialize array with real values
    labels = [WordLetterOne, WordLetterTwo, WordLetterThree, WordLetterFour, WordLetterFive]

    //you need to set the tags of each button in order for my method to work
    LetterOneButton.tag = 0
    LetterTwoButton.tag = 1
    LetterThreeButton.tag = 2
    LetterFourButton.tag = 3
    LetterFiveButton.tag = 4

}
```

For the index variable and arrays, make sure you initialize it OUTSIDE any function. Initialize them as class variables next to your labels and buttons like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterTwo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterThree: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFour: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WordLetterFive: UILabel!

var index: Int = 0

var labels: [UILabel] = [UILabel]() //empty intialization

var letters: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Then you need to change your other method to something like this:

```
@IBAction func LetterOneButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    //you can actually omit the switch statement in your case
    labels[index].text = letters[sender.tag]

    index += 1
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to link EVERY button to the above method. Do not have different methods for each button!

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that right away and let you know how it went!

Comment: It's not working (but I think I have done it wrong actually). Could you assist me further? I'm new to coding :( [This is what it looks like now](http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/codescreencroppgd5r8tcolj.png)

Comment: Sure, could you post the code of how you implemented it on your question? Then I can try and figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I have added the code in the original question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Janninho Okay, I updated my answer. Let me know if it works!!

Comment: Thanks for you effort, I really appreciate it! Now Xcode is complaining: (1) "Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel!' to expected element type 'String'" in the line with "var labels: [String] = [WordLetterOne [...]]", (2) "Use of unresolved identifier 'letters'" in the line with "labels[index].text = letters[sender.tag]" in the IBAction function.

Comment: @Janninho Hi yes, sorry, that's my bad. I updated the code, it should be correct now.

Comment: Less errors, but still one: "Cannot use instance member 'WordLetterOne' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" at the definition of "var labels:"

Comment: @Janninho Okay that is because Swift doesn't like you initializing an array of objects that haven't been loaded yet. To solve that, initialize the labels array with just an empty array and then set the values in the viewDidLoad method. I updated the code to reflect this. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will hep you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var x = 0, y = 0, buttonWidth = 50, buttonHeight = 50

    for i in 0...5 {
        let tempButton = UIButton()
        tempButton.frame = CGRect(x: (x+5), y: (y+5), width: (buttonWidth-10), height: (buttonHeight-10))
        tempButton.tag = i
        tempButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(withButton: tempButton)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        tempButton.backgroundColor = .red

        x += buttonWidth
        self.view.addSubview(tempButton)
    }
}
func buttonTapped(withButton button:UIButton){
        let label:UILabel = UILabel() //your label
        if(button.tag == 0){
            label.text = "I"
        }else if(button.tag == 1){
            label.text = "II"
        }else if(button.tag == 2){
            label.text = "III"
        }else if(button.tag == 3){
            label.text = "IV"
        }else if(button.tag == 4){
            label.text = "V"
        }

    }
```